# What does the orange striping in unanswered questions mean?

Tags: support, questions

Sorry to be such a newb, but I'm acclimatizing to this place :)

In unanswered questions, some questions are striped with orange and others not. I can't (easily) see why that is.

Why 'tis it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the yellow / orange background on some questions?

That indicates this question has one of your favorite tags on it.

> [image: picture]